# When matching url nested router not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have tried for several hours now but without success to identify the reason why this nested router does not work. In the following example in the main component a series of links are listed, among them `/surveys` that when matching will show the `<Surveys />` component, within this component when the url matches `/surveys/:id` the `<Answers />` component should be shown but it never shows. Could you help me identify the reason for this behavior

```
import ...

function App() {
  // some logic

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/employees">Employees</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/surveys">Surveys</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/survey-creator">Survey creator</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/survey-creator">
            <MySurveyCreator />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/employees">
            <Employees employees={state.employees} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/surveys" exact={true}>
            <Surveys />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/" exact={true}>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Surveys

```
import ...

function SingleSurvey({ id, name }) {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={`/surveys/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
    </li>
  );
}

export default function Surveys() {
  // some logic

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Survey</h1>
      <Switch>
        <ul>
          {surveys.map(survey => (
            <SingleSurvey key={survey.id} {...survey} />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <Route exact={true} path={`/${match.path}/:id`}>
          <Answers />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answers

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Answers() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  console.log(id);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Answer</h1>
      <h2>Current id is: {id}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you try to implement my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested route is in `Serveys` Component, So The `Serveys` Component has to match the url for the `nested route` but you put an `exact` keyword for it that won't match with the `/surveys/:id`

So in result you won't have a `Serveys` Component that `renders` `<Answers />` Component.

No Servey No Answer :)

just change this:

```
<Route path="/surveys" exact={true}>
    <Surveys />
</Route>
```

to this:

```
<Route path="/surveys">
    <Surveys />
</Route>
```